# FlutterError (dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope<Books?>>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before

Tags: flutter, initialization, state, provider

I have a code like following in `books_overview.dart`:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<Books>(context).fetchAndSetBooks(); 
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) {
      Provider.of<Books>(context).fetchAndSetBooks();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

And a code like below within `books.dart`

```
  Future<void> fetchAndSetBooks([bool filterByUser = false]) async {
    final filterString =
        filterByUser ? 'orderBy="creatorId"&equalTo="$userId"' : '';
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter-update.firebaseio.com/Books.json?auth=$authToken&$filterString');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (extractedData == null) {
        return;
      }
}
```

And I get the following error:

> FlutterError
> (dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope<Books?>>()
> or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before
> _BooksOverviewScreenState.initState() completed.

At this line of the code inside ``books_overview.dart`:

```
Provider.of<Books>(context).fetchAndSetBooks();
```

First of all, I would like to know is this a good way of using `provider` package(As the origin of the code is from a Flutter tutorial course)?

Secondly I like to know what is the problem and how can I fix it?

PS: I tried to change the first code as following but it didn't help:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      Provider.of<Contests>(context).fetchAndSetContests();
    });
  }
```